# Service discovery ASP.Net Core with Ocelot

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, ocelot

I may be wrong in my ideas but here the plan.

I have an app who has 2 services, with a client who consume these services.
Because I want them to be micro-services, I've planed to build an API Gateway to have only one access point and redirect requests.
I've found some docs for building this and I stumbled into Ocelot to do the job, it seems to fully answer my ideas.

But here the problem, if I want to run multiple instances of my services, I need a service discovery, that Ocelot can do with Consul, but it need in the service to register the service discovery provider in his configuration.
What I wanted to do is to discover services dynamically without configuring a service discovery provider in the services. Is it possible ?

Plus, if I want to run an another instance of the Gateway, the services will not register on this new instance.

Any hints or better solution ?